# GET in HTML and Not PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to process a GET extension in a HTML page and not a PHP page.

I have looked through the internet and not found anything.

URL = `examplesite.com?id=1234`

I assume this would go to the index page on the domain. As the index page is a HTML page, is there a way to get the details of the extension transferred to another link I have in the html script that emails me when someone looks at the site.

```
<script src="trigger.php">
</script>
```

This way I can customise the extension to know where the person found me. id=1234 is from twitter, id=2345 from FB etc.

Then i could place the extension onto the script to send me the email.

```
<script src="trigger.php?id=1234">
</script>
```

Is there a way to get the HTML page to process extension and pass it on in a variable of some sort.

Thanks in advance

Robert

Comment: html: no, php or js: yes

Comment: By "extension" do you mean the query parameters `id=1234`? You can put Javascript in the HTML page and it can access the query parameters.

Comment: Why don't you just make your index page a PHP script instead of HTML? You should be able to configure the server to use `index.php` as the index page.

Comment: or parse index.htm via php. a php script does not have to be *.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in Javascript in the HTML. `window.location.search` contains the query string from the URL.

You can then use an AJAX request to send the query string to your server script.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var script = 'trigger.php' + window.location.search;
    $.get(script);
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is not what the OP means. He wants to log the ID (email it to himself) every time a user visits the page.

Comment: @vikarjramun That's done by `trigger.php` on the server. He's just asking how to pass on the `id=1234` parameter to the script.

Comment: @vikarjramun this is the same as your 2nd paragraph, but better as it comes with code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with plain HTML. By definition, HTML is **not dynamic**. It can't process anything you want. However, there are three options.

Firstly, you can use JavaScript and AJAX calls to make another HTTP request to `examplesite.com/processID.php` (or another PHP page) which will process the request.

Another way to use JavaScript would be to use a client side API such as [MailChimp](https://mailchimp.com) to send the email directly from the users computer.

Or you could just redirect your root page for your domain `examplesite.com` to lead to index.php. I'm sure that's very easy to configure in mainstream servers such as Apache or Nginx. Otherwise please ask another question on Server Fault about how to set this up using your server.

If you are using a PHP hosting provider, they should also be able to help redirect the root page. If you don't have any access to PHP on your hosting provider, you're out of luck. You must only use the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with ajax

```html
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="submit" id="sendforms">send</button> 
    </form>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    
     <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#sendforms").click(function() {
                       var combinedFormData = $("#form1").serialize();
                     $.get(
                            "trigger.php",
                            combinedFormData
                     ).done(function(data) {
                            //alert("Successfully submitted!");
                            $("#result").html(data);
                     }).fail(function () {
                              //alert("Error submitting forms!");
                     })
              });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: I dont know why you would do that with the form? I am trying to find out what media the person clicked the link from to get to the site and transfer the information to the PHP trigger. I dont want a form on the page.